# Get local computer name via Citrix session in .NET

Tags: .net, citrix

I need to get the local Computer Name for a desktop computer running our software application through a Citrix session. When I query `My.Computer.Name` I get the name of the server.

How can I get the name of the actual physical computer that the session is running on, and is there there an event I can monitor for when someone switches a session from one computer to another?

Comment: I don't have a Citrix server ready, but IIRC there should be a variable on the server environment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found a server variable as Kobi suggested above:

`%CLIENTNAME%`

it is only populated in Terminal Services or Citrix, expanding it on you local PC will return `%CLIENTNAME%`. However, on a citrix or RDP server it works great. The .net code I am using is:

`TSHostName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%CLIENTNAME%")`

Comment: Well, at least you spelled the name right `:)`.  You can accept your own answer, by the way, by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Comment: Sorry mate. Fixed it! New to stockoverflow, thanks for your help.