# Access client machine details when access through citrix

Tags: asp.net, citrix

I have to make my application work in citrix. I have a desktop application which inserts PC name and its default printername to DB when it launches. So if I use citrix for accessing this application, how I get the PC name and its default printer name?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the PC name from an environment variable, see this post:

[Get local computer name via Citrix session in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329236/get-local-computer-name-via-citrix-session-in-net)

If client printer redirection is enabled AFAIK you should be able to get the printer name using the same APIs you use now for the desktop version of your app. Configuring printer redirection is something the Citrix administrator needs to configure.